# AngularJS: Proper scope binding when dynamically compiling a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

### Given

- directive D1 applied to an element E
- directive D1 is passed a template that contains directive D2
- directive D2 is subscribed to **ngModel** updates
- directive D1 compiles template with directive D2
- directives D1 and D2 are considered to be independent of each other
- directives D1 and D2 have isolated scopes
- (directive D1 might be detached from the DOM, but kept in memory)

### Objective

- make directive D2 react to scope changes of element E with applied D1 to it

---

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<label>
    <u>model: </u>
    <input type="text" ng-model="someValue" outer="tmpl.html"/>
    <hr/>
</label>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="tmpl.html">
    <inner test="123"></inner>
</script>

<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

---

**app.js**

```
(function (ng) {

var app = ng.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.someValue = 'Hello, World!';
    }
])
// directive D2
.directive('inner', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<p>{{model || "N/A"}}</p>',
        scope: { model: '=ngModel' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('model', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!ng.isDefined(oldValue) && !ng.isDefined(newValue)) {
                  return;
                }
                // do stuff...
            });
        }
    };
})
// directive D1
.directive('outer', [
    '$templateCache',
    '$compile',
    function ($templateCache, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {},
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var template = $templateCache.get(attrs.outer);
                var compiled = $compile(template)(scope);
                element.parent().append(compiled);
            }
      };
    }
]);

})(angular);
```

### Fiddle

An overly simplified version is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nscp8/12/

### Example

**D1** is a popover widget that can be configured to insert HTML as its contents.
**D2** is a QR-code widget that watches the model and updates on change.

### Problem

The ngModel binding is not done properly and I don't get updates from it. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scope: { model: '=ngModel' },`

This binds the property `model` to the property defined in the attribute `ng-model` of the **`inner`** element, since you use the directive in form of an element. Your `inner` element does not have such an attribute.

But even if it had, the second problem would be that the parent scope of `inner` is the scope of `outer`, which is an isolate scope as well. `someValue` is defined in the controller´s scope, so `inner` has no chance to directly establish a binding with `someValue`, regardless of the type of binding you choose.

The solution depends on your specific needs. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nscp8/13/) for one possible solution.

Comment: @JohnDoe D2 depends on E (well, its `ng-model` in fact) and the only link between those two is D1. So you can either use another D1, that is aware of D2, or another D2 (i.e. template) that is aware of the model.